# Geometric interpretation of KKT conditions

Tags: kkt-conditions, lagrange-multipliers

I can explain why Lagrange multipliers work for scalar functions by vector calculus. Consider optimizing $f(\vec{x})$ subjected to the constraint $g(\vec{x}) = c$.

At the optima, we can move infinitesimally within the feasible region without changing the value of $f(\vec{x})$. This infinitesimal movement (and any movement in the feasible region) must be along the constraint, which is one level curve of $g$. Since the infinitesimal movement doesn't change the value of $f$, the infinitesimal movement is also along the level curve of $f$.

As the gradient of a function at any point is perpendicular to the function's level curve, we have $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$.

Where can I find a similar explanation for KKT conditions?

Comment: Take a look at chapters 4 and 5 of this [book](https://labs.xjtudlc.com/labs/wldmt1/books/Optimization/Nonlinear%20programming%20Theory%20and%20Algorithms.pdf). The link is to the book Non-linear programming by Bazarra.